# Eclipse C undefined reference to x

Tags: c, linux, eclipse

I'm using Eclipse (Kepler) on a Debian VM to cross compile to a linux system (Yocto Project i586/32).

I'm new to Eclipse, so forgive my ignorance.

I have a 'HelloWorld' program that builds and runs fine.
I wanted to add another c file and header, so I used File / New / Header and File / New Source file to create the files, populate them and write the code.

They are very simple, the header declares one function (makeDaemon) and a bunch of flags and the c file implements the function.

In my 'HelloWorld.c" file I have #include'd the new header file. (`#include "makeDaemon.h"`)

At build time I get a build error - **undefined reference to 'makeDaemon'** - I have checked all the spellings and so on. I have hit 'refresh' on the project and src folder.

So it looks like the compiler is not including my new c file in the build? Do I somehow have to add it to a makefile somewhere?

Comment: If you are new to Eclipse and if you want to compile C code, consider *not learning Eclipse* and compile on the command line (e.g. with `gcc` or `make`); it is probably not worth using Eclipse for C programs if you are a newbie to Eclipse.

Comment: The device I am writing for runs in a very small amount of memory, with no room for installing dev tools on the device.

Comment: It is a comment, not an answer. You could use cross-compilers (or perhaps simply `gcc -m32` under Linux/x86-64 if the target processor is 32 bits x86).

Comment: I am using a cross compiler. The only tools available for targeting this device are provided by the manufacturer as a VM using Eclipse.

Comment: >>It is a comment, not an answer. 
Yes - sorry I realised that almost as soon as I posted the return comment.

Comment: are you sure the error is "undefined reference to 'makeDaemon'", but not "makeDaemon.h, no such file or direcotry?", so you know what I am guessing?

Comment: Yes definitely. It sees the header, and I know that because I can put deliberate mistakes in the header to check.